# Remove a[href] with jQuery

Tags: href

I need remove a[href] from the following html:

```
<span class="fl-post-info-author">
<a href="/author/name/“>Author Name</a>
</span>

$('span.fl-post-info-author a').removeAttr("href");
```

I've tried this but am not sure how to target the href. I'm trying to disable the link entirely, and want the text to stay, just not be a link. It's a post meta link in WordPress.

Comment: This will work. But run either after load or after this html part. More efficient would be `$('.fl-post-info-author').find('a').removeAttr("href");`

Comment: It works https://jsfiddle.net/jypk8c64/

Comment: How is that more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your jQuery code is executed only when the document enters the `ready` state by wrapping it in a `$(document).ready()` function block:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span.fl-post-info-author a').removeAttr("href");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="fl-post-info-author">
<a href="/author/name/">Author Name</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I had tried that but it didn't work. However, I failed to check the console, and just did. WordPress doesn't like $, it likes jQuery instead. It says $ is not a function. So I replaced $ with jQuery and it works.